# Regex - occurrences of a batch of keywords in a text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm doing keyword extraction on documents.

Entries are :

- thousands of documents (up to 2GB in size)
- about ~200k keywords aggregated by categories

As of now, for every document, we search every keyword one by one, which I think is inefficient.

So I thought about compiling regexes by category of keywords using pipes:

```
import re

text = """
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
making it over 2000 years old.
Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia,
looked up one of the more obscure Latin words,
consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage,
and going through the cites of the word in classical literature,
discovered the undoubtable source.
Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of
"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero,
written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics,
very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum,
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. 
"""

regexes = [
    r'(?P<Writing__book>book)',
    r'(?P<Writing__word>word)',
    r'(?P<Writing__latin>latin)',
    r'(?P<Writing__text>text)',
    r'(?P<Writing__literature>literature)',
    r'(?P<Cities__virginia>virginia)',
    r'(?P<Genre__classical>classical)',
    r'(?P<Genre__renaissance>renaissance)',
]
compiled_regex = '|'.join(regexes)
results = re.findall(
        compiled_regex,
        text,
        flags=re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE
    )
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

This prints:

```
('', '', '', 'text', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', '', 'classical', '')
('', '', 'Latin', '', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', 'literature', '', '', '')
('', '', 'Latin', '', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', 'Virginia', '', '')
('', '', 'Latin', '', '', '', '', '')
('', 'word', '', '', '', '', '', '')
('', 'word', '', '', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', '', 'classical', '')
('', '', '', '', 'literature', '', '', '')
('book', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
('', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Renaissance')
```

What I'd like to get is a dictionary with each `category__keyword` and the number of occurrences, like:

```
{'Writing__book': 1, 'Writing__word': 2, 'Cities__virginia': 1, ...}
```

Comment: I know you're using *Python* and that my comment isn't giving you a good advise but did you by any chance try to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)? It's incredibly fast compared to *grep*, *ag* or other tools and has some cache mechanisms that might be efficiant if you run the search for each keyword on the same input files. Typically `rg -c '\bbook\b' /path/to/folder` would output the number of occurences for each file. You could then extract these values and create all your statistics and sum the counters for each keyword.

Comment: You count `Writing__word` as 2, but that is because you are matching the word `words` in the text. However, matching `words` the way you are means `word` will also match `sword`, which I presume you don't actually want.

Comment: You're totally right @Nick :-) This is also why I added the word boundary `\b` in my proposition using *ripgrep*. By the way, your answer is very interesting. I'm a novice in *Python* so I wasn't able to reply. But I would be very interested to see some benchmarks with several solutions so that we know what is best to implement!

Comment: @PatrickJanser I ran tests using `timeit` and my solution is about 40% faster; I would expect that advantage to increase as the number of search words (and hence the regex complexity) went up.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the timing. But the use case is reading a lot of huge files (up to 2Go) on disk so timing this little *Python* script with probably only 1ko of input text in memory isn't really a valuable comparaison. Imagine what happens when you lowercase and split your 2Go string into an array of words? Using some optimized search tools using caching and multi-threaded mechanisms might get faster. We don't really know and it's probably only the author of the question who can do some benchmarking.

Comment: @PatrickJanser all good points, although really 2GB is not that much memory these days. I've got 64 sitting under my desk. But yes, it's really up to OP to test these things out on their actual data and system, and it would be interesting to see the results...

Comment: @PatrickJanser I've spent some more time looking at performance. Check out the other answer I've posted.

Comment: @Nick That’s great! Thanks a lot for the very interesting benchmark and improvements!

Comment: @PatrickJanser no worries - I can't help myself sometimes :) but it definitely proved productive for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes on performance. All testing was done using `timeit` with 1 iterations of the code on a dual Xeon server with 192GB RAM and SSD drives. The following functions were used (note that I've only including the counting code, since for large files that will vastly outweigh any reformatting cost):

```py
def count_sushanth(text, regex):
    results = re.finditer(
        regex,
        text,
        flags=re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE
    )

    word_counts = defaultdict(int)  # <-- Default dict to track counts

    for result in results:
        for key_, value_ in result.groupdict().items():  # <-- Use group dict, since the you have named capturing group
            if value_:
                word_counts[key_] += 1

def count_nick(text):
    counts = Counter(re.split(r'\s*[^a-z0-9]', text.lower()))
```

The sample data from the question was used, but expanded 1M times (`text = text * 1_000_000`) to make it about 750MB.

The results for the original code were `count_sushanth` : 114.35 seconds; `count_nick` : 68.72 seconds.

Not great. It did occur to me that my code was not as optimal as it might be so I modified it to just find words instead:

```
def count_nick_new(text):
    return Counter(map(str.lower, re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', text)))
```

This gave a bit of an improvement to `43.51` seconds. What about the power of the word break (`\b`)?

```
def count_nick_new_wb(text):
    return Counter(map(str.lower, re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b', text)))
```

Now we're talking: `0.55` seconds - an almost 100x improvement in speed. Applying the same optimisation to sushanth's code:

```
sushanth_regex_new = r'\b(' + '|'.join(regexes) + r')\b'
```

gives `0.56` seconds and has the added benefit of preventing `word` matching `wordle` and `sword`.

So what about compiling the regex?

```
nick_regex_comp = re.compile(nick_regex)

def count_nick_new_comp(text, compiled_regex):
    return Counter(map(str.lower, compiled_regex.findall(text)))

sushanth_regex_comp = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(regexes) + r')\b', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

def count_sushanth_comp(text, regex):
    results = regex.finditer(text)
    word_counts = defaultdict(int)  # <-- Default dict to track counts
    for result in results:
        for key_, value_ in result.groupdict().items():  # <-- Use group dict, since the you have named capturing group
            if value_:
                word_counts[key_] += 1
    return word_counts
```

In both cases this actually had minimal effect on the performance of the code, suggesting that most of the time is being spent processing the results of the `find`.

Since my code was spending time in lower-casing all the results, I thought I'd try lower-casing the entire text:

```
def count_nick_new_lower(text):
    return Counter(re.findall(r'\b[a-z]+\b', text.lower()))
```

This actually caused about a 2.5x slowdown, to 1.31 seconds.

I also tried using an iterator in my code:

```
def count_nick_new_iter(text, regex):
    return Counter(map(lambda m:m.group().lower(), re.finditer(regex, text)))
```

This had no effect on performance; probably because the entire string could be held in memory anyway.

Final summary of results:

| function | time | notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| count_sushanth | 114.35 | matches `sword` and `wordle` to `word` |
| count_nick | 68.72 | only deals with single word search terms |
| count_nick_new | 43.51 |  |
| count_nick_new_wb | 0.55 |  |
| count_sushanth_wb | 0.56 | solves the mismatching problem too! |
| count_nick_new_comp | 0.55 | no performance improvement for regex compilation |
| count_sushanth_comp | 0.55 | very minor performance improvement |
| count_nick_new_lower | 1.31 | Significant penalty to lower-case the entire text |
| count_nick_new_iter | 0.55 | no change |

Comment: By the way "The power of the word break" is incredible!

Comment: Ah finally I'll use Sushanth's, thing is there are keywords with spaces, dashes, etc. There are even keywords that are regular expressions, so going with regex seems the best way to do it for me.
Though your method will certainly be useful for others. Thanks again!

Comment: @Loïc yeah, if you need to have keywords with spaces (or which are regex themselves) that is definitely the way to go. Anyway, this has been an interesting exercise for me and I'm glad it was helpful for you.

Comment: that benchmark is awesome, thanks a lot, hopefully you had fun and as well that it will help others.

Comment: @Loïc yeah I did have fun with it. Always nice to see whether your expectations of how code runs matches real life.

Comment: Mines are how cool some guys are to play the game and help others. Got to say you rock at this friend.

Answer (score 3):

You could search for all words (sequences of letters) using a regex and then count words using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Then use a comprehension over a dictionary of words in each category to build your desired result:

```py
from collections import Counter

words = { 'Writing' : ['word', 'book', 'latin', 'text', 'literature'],
          'Cities' : ['virginia'],
          'Genre' : ['classical', 'renaissance']
        }
counts = Counter(map(str.lower, re.findall(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b', text)))
result = { f'{k}__{w}' : counts[w] for k, v in words.items() for w in v }
```

Output:

```
{
    "Writing__word": 1,
    "Writing__book": 1,
    "Writing__latin": 3,
    "Writing__text": 1,
    "Writing__literature": 2,
    "Cities__virginia": 1,
    "Genre__classical": 2,
    "Genre__renaissance": 1
}
```

Better yet, produce a dict of dict of counts:

```
result = { k : { w : counts[w] for w in v } for k, v in words.items() }
```

Output:

```
{
    "Writing": {
        "word": 1,
        "book": 1,
        "latin": 3,
        "text": 1,
        "literature": 2,
        "fred": 0
    },
    "Cities": {
        "virginia": 1
    },
    "Genre": {
        "classical": 2,
        "renaissance": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful solution. Sadly, as a coworker told me, some keywords contain spaces, so splitting the text into a list of words won't work.

Comment: Then later we will probably implement this for all the keywords made of only one word. Thank you again.

Comment: @Loïc please see my new answer for some interesting performance data. Both the originally posted answers are far worse than they could be.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution you can try,

```
import re

from collections import defaultdict

text = """..."""

regexes = ["..."]

compiled_regex = '|'.join(regexes)

results = re.finditer(  # <-- Change to finditer, which returns a iterator (efficient on large data)
    compiled_regex,
    text,
    flags=re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE
)

word_counts = defaultdict(int)  # <-- Default dict to track counts

for result in results:
    for key_, value_ in result.groupdict().items():  # <-- Use group dict, since the you have named capturing group
        if value_:
            word_counts[key_] += 1

print(word_counts)
```

---

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Writing__text': 1, 'Genre__classical': 2, 'Writing__latin': 3, 'Writing__literature': 2, 'Cities__virginia': 1, 'Writing__word': 2, 'Writing__book': 1, 'Genre__renaissance': 1})
```

Comment: This is not actually correct; it counts `Writing__word` as 2, but that is because it is matching `word` with the word `words` in the text. However, matching `words` the way it does means `word` will also match `sword`, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

(untested) But I would do something like:

```
# May need to remove other punctuation here using .replace()
input_as_list = text.split(" ").replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("(", "").replace('"', "")

# Add any desired words here
words_to_find = ["book", "word", "latin"]

# Output dict
output = {}

for word in words_to_find:
    output[word] = input_as_list.count(word)

print(output)
```

This will return something that looks like:

```
{"book": 7, "word": 5, "latin": 3}
```

Using Python built-in string methods is recommended over regex as their behavior is more clear.